# How to pass a function as method argument

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am trying to pass a function as an argument to a method of class. I know I need to use proc, but I am not sure I am using the right syntax. This is my attempt.

```
module MyApp;end
module MyApp::Stats
  def self.sum(a)
    a.inject(0){ |accum, i| accum + i }
  end

  def self.mean(a)
    sum(a) / a.length.to_f
  end
  # Many more functions....      

  def self.sum_proc
    Proc.new{|x| sum(x) }
  end

  def self.mean_proc
    Proc.new{|x| mean(x)}
  end
  # And many more procs

end

class MyData
  attr_reader :values
  attr_reader :aggregates

  def initialize(array)
    @values = array
    @aggregates = {}
  end

  def aggregate(aggregator)
    puts aggregator.call(@values)
    #I would also like to create a hash of aggregator. Something like:
    #aggregates["aggregator"] = aggregator.call(@values) 
  end

end
```

I can then do

```
ar = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
data = MyData.new(ar)
```

And call the `aggregate` method in various ways:

```
aggregator = Proc.new{|x| MyApp::Stats.sum(x)}
data.aggregate(aggregator)

data.aggregate(Proc.new{|x| MyApp::Stats.mean(x)} )

data.aggregate(Proc.new{|x| x.count{|y| y > 3.0} })

data.aggregate(MyApp::Stats.sum_proc)

data.aggregate(MyApp::Stats.mean_proc)
```

I have two issues with this code. First it seems redundant as I have to define the aggregator first and then the associated proc, e.g. `sum` and `sum_proc`. Second, I wonder how I could pass any of the standard `enumerator` methods without defining a proc for it: say `count` or `first`.

Finally, I would like to create a hash for the aggregators so that I could do:

```
puts data.aggregates["sum"]
puts data.aggregates["mean"]
```

Comment: This seems very unRubyish. Why are you using `proc`s instead of blocks or methods? Would it not make more sense to say `data.aggregate { |x| x.count { |y| y > 3.0 } }` directly, or `data.aggregate(&MyApp::Stats.method(:sum))`? It is extremely rare that overt `Proc` is necessary in Ruby.

Comment: @Amadan `data.aggregate(&MyApp::Stats.method(:sum))` would return the `ArgumentError` according to `sum` method implementation.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: `sum` is fine; I am proposing that `aggregates` taking a proc is unRubyish and it should take a block instead (replacing `aggregator.call(@values)` with `yield @values`).

Comment: @Amadan the reason I am using procs is that I want to be able to use the name of the aggregator in the method call. Also `mean` and `sum` are very simple examples. Other aggregators like `standard_deviation` are more complex and the expression within the block would become a bit cryptic.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko `data.aggregate(MyApp::Stats.method(:mean).to_proc)` would work. Ideally I would like to write `data.aggregate(mean). Maybe I could use an alias for that: something like `alias mean MyApp::Stats.method'

Comment: Still makes no sense to make `Proc` being the default; there is nowhere in Core that you have API that works like that. If you want to pass in a `Proc`, you can easily blockify it using `&`, as I show in my examples. On my machine, passing a block is about 5.5 times faster than passing a `Proc` if you construct it every time, 60% faster if you construct the `Proc` beforehand. `Proc`s are *heavy*.

Comment: Alternately, if you know that all of your aggregators will be defined on the same object, you could just take a symbol argument (`data.aggregate(:mean)`) and then send the symbol to the defining class (`MyApp::Stats.send(aggregator, @values)`). Superfast, syntactically clean. I'll risk sounding like a broken record, but overuse of `Proc` is a telling symptom of someone not being used to Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

Methods aren't objects in Ruby. You can't pass a method as an argument because you can only pass objects as arguments.

However, you can get a `Method` proxy object representing a method by calling the `method` method and passing the name of the method as an argument. `Method` proxy objects duck-type `Proc`, so they respond to `arity`, `parameters`, and most importantly `to_proc` and `call`.

The idiomatic way of taking a *single* first-class procedure as an argument, is to take a block like this:

```
def aggregate
  yield @values
end
```

and pass a method using the unary prefix `&` operator:

```
data.aggregate(&MyApp::Stats.:sum)
```

Comment: How would I pass an argument? If one of the aggregators is `def self.gt(a,t);a.count{|x| x > t};end`. I guess I should pass arguments to yield, but can't figure out the syntax.